# composer.lock: how does it work?

Tags: php, dependency-management, package-managers, composer-php

I'm trying to understand this part: http://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#lock-file

> this lock file will not have any effect on other projects that depend on it. It only has an effect on the main project"

Does that mean that if project P depends on library A, and library A depends on library B v1.3, project P won't care about the version of library B, and will possibly install B 1.4 instead? What's the point then?

Or does it mean the opposite, as one would expect from a dependency manager?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Composer dependencies are defined in `composer.json`. When running composer install for the first time, or when running composer update a lock file called `composer.lock` will be created. <sup>1</sup>

The quoted documentation refers to the lock file only. If your project P depends on library A and A depends on B v1.3.***, then if A contains a lock file saying someone ran "composer update" resulting in B v1.3.2 being installed, then installing A in your project P might still install 1.3.3, as the `composer.json` (not `.lock`!) defined the dependency to be on 1.3.*.

Lock files always contain exact version numbers, and are useful to communicate the version you tested with to colleagues or when publishing an application. For libraries the dependency information in `composer.json` is all that matters.

---

<sup>1</sup> `composer.lock` is created by default as the *`lock` configuration option*<sup>[[ref](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#lock)]</sup> is `true`. Setting the option to `false` Composer won't create nor read the `composer.lock` file.

Comment: How would one update all the dependencies to what is specified in a lock file (such as when transferring a project from staging to live)?

Comment: Simply run composer.phar install - which installs/updates/removes everything to the state of the lock file

Comment: In Python and Ruby, there's a similar concept involving the Gemfile.lock and requirements.txt. See: https://caremad.io/blog/setup-vs-requirement/ and http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/ Doesn't that mean, that for PHP "Libraries" the compooser.lock does not need to be kept. but for PHP "Applications" the composer.lock should be committed?

Comment: The composer.lock file can be beneficial for libraries too. Not for anyone depending on the library, but for developers of the library who communicate which versions they installed to run tests or debug issues, it can also help clarify which versions of dependencies the CI system ran tests for the library with.

Comment: composer.lock is like meta data for composer.json file

Answer (score 138):

`composer.lock` records the exact versions that are installed. So that you are in the same versions with your co-workers.

**composer install**

- Check for `composer.lock` file
- If not, auto generate `composer.lock` file (Using `composer update`)
- Install the specified versions recorded in the `composer.lock` file

**composer update**

- Go through the `composer.json` file
- Check availability of newer (latest) versions, based on the version criteria mentioned (e.g. 1.12.*)
- Install the latest possible (according to above) versions
- Update `composer.lock` file with installed versions

---

*So in a simple check list.*

**If you want to keep all co-workers in the same versions as you...**

- Commit your `composer.lock` to GIT (or vcs you have)
- Ask others to get the that version of `composer.lock` file
- **Always use** `composer install` to get the correct dependencies

**If you want to Upgrade the system dependencies to new versions**

- Check the composer.json file for version specs.
- Do a `composer update`
- This will change the `composer.lock` file with newest versions
- Commit it to the GIT (or vcs)
- Ask others to get it and `composer install`

Following will be a very good reading 
https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/composer-its-all-about-the-lock-file

Enjoy the power of `composer.lock` file!

Comment: I would also like to point out that composer install, sometimes doesn't get the versions you wanted when they are already installed, as a workaround they have to delete the vendor folder and composer install again in order to get the right version in composer.lock. 

e.g. I'm getting 4.0.1 instead of 4.0.14-beta from my vendor after composer installing, I deleted the vendor then composer install again then I got the right version 4.0.14-beta

Answer (score 8):

The point of the lock file is to record the exact versions that are installed so they can be re-installed. This means that if you have a version spec of 1.* and your co-worker runs `composer update` which installs 1.2.4, and then commits the composer.lock file, when you `composer install`, you will also get 1.2.4, even if 1.3.0 has been released. This ensures everybody working on the project has the same exact version.Read more here [Composer: It’s All About the Lock File](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/composer-its-all-about-the-lock-file)

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
compose init
```

it will resolve your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).