# What's the difference between composer.lock and installed.json?

Tags: composer-php

I understand that `composer.lock` is meant to pin down the exact version of the installed dependencies. But what purpose does the `vendor/composer/installed.json` file play?

Both contain JSON and both are generated automatically.

Comment: Very good answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39502171/3648564.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`composer.lock` is generated when installing for the first time or updating. It contains references to the exact versions used. It should be committed into the version tracking repository to allow restoring this exact combination of libraries.

`installed.json` is an internal file of Composer. It's used when you remove a package manually from `composer.json` to remove the files from the vendor directory. Otherwise, the old vendor package would be around forever.

Comment: The reason I asked was precisely because I'm working on a project where the `vendor/` dir is under version control, for reasons I won't go into here. In such a scenario, it seems prudent to commit it along with everything else.

Comment: A very valid reason would be that the deployment process does not currently allow to fetch the dependencies independently. But even in that case I wouldn't even try to touch anything inside `vendor`, only commit it as it is after the install/update.

Comment: Should I push installed.json or not

Comment: might anything be messed up when installed.json is deleted then?

Comment: Couldn't Composer just as easily refer to `composer.lock` instead of `installed.json` when a package is manually removed from `composer.json`?

Comment: Pay attention when you change a package repository source url ie: if you fork a repo to use a custom version seems composer will ignore the new url, I suspect installed.json must be modified to remove old url

Answer (score 1):

`installed.json` appears to be used by Composer as an internal repository to keep track of what has actually been installed in the vendor directory.

I've read that `composer.lock` is what **should** be installed and `installed.json` is what **is** installed. This make some sense in the context that that its valid to have a composer.lock file without a vendor directory. You run `composer install` and it will install the packages listed int `composer.lock` and write them to `installed.json`.

Composers codebase treats `installed.json` as a local repository. The contents are loaded into a variable of type `InstalledRepositoryInterface` which is named `localRepository`.