# Why composer was designed to work with two files: composer.json and composer.lock, instead of one

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to create my own package manager, and currently reviewing existing solutions.

I'm playing with PHP's Composer now, and it was quite surprising that it has two files:

- `composer.json` for project configuration, and non-pinned dependencies
- `composer.lock` for exact pinned dependencies

I do understand why one needs to pin dependencies, `.lock` information by itself seems logical to me.

What I do not understand is why project metadata was split into two files.

Can anyone explain, why it was designed this way? Why deps could not be pinned right in the `composer.json`?

UPD. Turns out, Rust's Cargo has the same two file configuration in place, and has a nice explanation of the meaning of the `.lock` file: http://doc.crates.io/guide.html#cargotoml-vs-cargolock

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674641/composer-lock-how-does-it-work

Comment: Still don't understand. So, if I'm using project as a standalone app, I'm using `.lock` and I'm happy with it.
When I'm using project as a third-party app, I'm not using it's own `.lock`, but info that is placed in the `.json` to install library dependencies, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.lock` information is absolutely pinned, typically created by a `composer update` request based on the `json` information... but developers don't necessarily want to pin everything to an exact version, and without that `.json` file they have to upgrade the `.lock` file manually for every version upgrade of their dependencies.

The `.lock` also holds dependencies of dependencies, and dependencies of dependencies of dependencies, etc... whereas the `.json` file only holds immediate dependencies.... and as a developer, you should only need to control your immediate dependencies, and allow those libraries to control their own dependencies via their own `.json` files

Basically, you should build your application against the `json` but deploy against the `.lock`

Answer (score 3):

During development, you usually want to be able to upgrade to the latest compatible version of dependencies easily. `composer.json` has the information on what the dependencies are and which versions are compatible. `composer.lock` lacks the compatibility information, it may say that the package was built against version 2.2.7 of a dependency but information is missing about rules such as that versions >= 2.1 and < 3 of that dependency are compatible while lower versions aren't and the next major version isn't guaranteed to be so play it safe.

When building for testing or release, on the other hand, it's necessary to make sure you build against the exact same set of dependency versions every time. `composer.lock` allows that by listing out the exact versions used. Even if new versions of dependencies come out, the dependency pinning insures that the build won't change so you won't have to worry about changes in behavior caused by changes in dependency packages.