# specifying different versions in composer json and lock file

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to know what will happen if I have different dependency versions in `composer.json` and `composer.lock` and try to `composer install`.

Here are different versions (e.g) that I want to know:

```
composer.json : 1.0.3
composer.lock : 1.0.1
```

Will the package v1.0.1 installed? or v1.0.3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [composer.lock: how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674641/composer-lock-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Check the answer by @Dilhan Maduranga

Comment: why don't you try it yourself? and check the produced output composer will in this case directly tell what is going on and what it detected